# run css animation when visible on scroll

Tags: html, css, animation, scroll, visible

I'm creating my test webpage and I ran into a problem, there are quite a few "answers" on my issue but none was I able to implement in my code. I know I have to use javascript but I was not able to get it working.

So, I need to run css animation of movement on chosen picture, when that picture is visible on screen when I scroll down to it. Basically like on this page: https://www.photoblog.com/

So I have this code in the html as for the picture:

```
<img class="movepic" src="pictures/test.jpg">
```

And then there is this simple code for the CSS movement:

```
.movepic {
position: relative;
animation-name: move;
animation-duration: 3s;
visibility: visible;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
z-index:10;
}
@keyframes move {
0% { right:0px; top:150px;}
100% {right:700px; top:150px;}
}
```

Is there a way to make it work so I do not need to completely redo this? Or if so, could some please give me a advice how to do it maybe with code ilustration.

Thanks a lot

Comment: When scrollTop = containerOffset.top ---> addClass for animation

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `animation-name` from your style rule:

```
.movepic {
    position: relative;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
    visibility: visible;
    z-index:10;
}
```

and add this class to stylesheet:

```
.animation-class {
    animation-name: move
}
```

Now add the jQuery:

```
var has_fired;
$("html").on("scroll", function () {
    if (!has_fired && $(this).scrollTop() >= $("#imgContainer").offset().top) {
        $("#imgContainer").addClass("animation-class");
        has_fired = true; // use this if only want fired once
    }
});
```

The animation will now run. BTW I would add an ID (imgContainer) to your container of interest and use this as selector for matching because unless .movepic is a unique class, this function will fire for any container with the .movepic class (if .movepic is the selector).

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for this effect:

**HTML**:

```
<img class="movepic" src="pictures/test.jpg">
```

**CSS**:

```
.movepic {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 25px 0 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
 }

.FadeIn {
    -webkit-animation: slideIn 0.8s ease 0.3s forwards;
    animation: slideIn 0.8s ease 0.3s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**JQuery**:

```
var $fade =  $(".movepic"); //Calling the class in HTML

$(window).scroll(function () { //Using the scroll global variable
    $fade.each(function () {

        fadeMiddle = $(this).offset().top + (0.4 *$(this).height());
        windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if (fadeMiddle < windowBottom) {
          $(this).addClass("FadeIn");
        }
    });
});

/* On Load: Trigger Scroll Once*/
$(window).scroll();
```